# Trigger event on clicking both on checkbox or row in kendo UI grid

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, multiple-select

My kendo grid looks like:

[image]

I have `change/dataBound` methods used to both check the box and highlight selected row:

```js
change: function (e) {
    $('tr').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false).removeAttr('aria-selected');
    $('tr.k-state-selected').find('[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);                 
},
dataBound: function (e) {
    $(".checkbox").bind("click", function (e) {
        $(e.target).closest("tr").toggleClass("k-state-selected");
    });
},
```

I need to get data when one row is selected, and I can do it in `change` method by extracting `dataItem` from selected row. Problem is, `change` method is triggered only when I click on whole row, but not when I click on checkbox. How can I trigger event on both clicking on checkbox or row?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to get the dataitem for the row when the checkbox is clicked you should be able use something like this:

```js
dataBound: function (e) {
    $(".checkbox").bind("click", function (e) {
        $(e.target).closest("tr").toggleClass("k-state-selected");
        var myItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    });
},

// might need to update the reference to grid for your grid instance
```

Very close to the method used to get the data item in a custom command http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command